# Multiligual change current page

Tags: php, multilingual

hi just wonder what is the best practice for me do work with multilingual so that whenever the user change the language it will return the same page with language choose.

Let say i'm having this for changing language

```
<a href="index.php?lang=en"><img src="images/en.png" /></a>
<a href="index.php?lang=de"><img src="images/de.png" /></a>
```

I don't want change the index.php to respective page name. Is there anyway for me to do that?
Should i use

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>
```

And what if my URL already have variable(s) to pass, how can i add the lang variable?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do `Conditional statements` i.e **If / else**

*For e.g:*

```
if(isset($_GET['lang']) == "en") {
//English content here
}if(isset($_GET['lang']) == "fr") {
//French content here
}
```

**Note:** You need to pass the `lang` variable through each link so that the user will remain in the same language at every page.

Comment: yes i did use conditional using separate file. My problem is for example in index.php there's a link to edit.php page with passing varible (edit.php?id=12) so when i click the link it only pass varible id, not include lang. and when ever i click to change other language in edit.php, the varible (id) that passed before is gone. Did i have to amend all my a href to put variable lang?or is there any simple way for me to do that?

Comment: Yes you need to add another parameter to your anchor tag something like that:
<a href=`"edit.php?id=12&lang=en"` >Edit</a>